# CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Look_UpData.TableType' to 'LookUpData.Core.Domain.TableType'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
public class TableTypeRepository : ITableTypeRepository
{
    private TrenStarEAMEntities db = new TrenStarEAMEntities();
    Core.Domain.TableType ITableTypeRepository.GetTableType(short id)
    {
        using (TrenStarEAMEntities dbContext = new TrenStarEAMEntities.Data.TrenStarEAMEntities())
        {
            var HttpStatusCoderesult = dbContext.GetTableType(null);
            Core.Domain.TableType tableType = db.TableTypes.Find(id);
            if (tableType == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(tableType);
        }
    }

    private Core.Domain.TableType View(Core.Domain.TableType tableType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private Core.Domain.TableType HttpNotFound()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    Core.Domain.TableType ITableTypeRepository.GetTableType(short id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This is where the error is GetTableType(short id) can anyone help?

Comment: How many places you have the `TableType` class defined ? As per the error, you have it in 2 places are you are trying to use both! Delete one.

Comment: You have other problems as well. You are trying to return 2 different types from same method ! (Both `HttpNotFound` and `TableType`) and that will give you a compiler error because your method's return type is `TableType`